# How to update any field before firing the save event in force:recordEdit

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, force-recordedit

I have a usecase where I want to update some field values at the record before firing the `component.find("edit").get("e.recordSave").fire()` event.

Here is the markup which I am using

```
<force:recordEdit aura:id="edit" recordId="0069000000PUrus"/>
<lightning:button label="Save &amp; Next" onclick="{!c.doSaveAction}" />
```

**Controller**

```
doSaveAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    // Here, can I update a field value before sending record to save event
    component.find("edit").get("e.recordSave").fire();
}
```

Please let me know if it is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't done this with force:recordEdit but I have done it with Lightning:recordEdit so if thats an option you could just switch to that and the code below will allow you to update object fields before they are passed to the server.  Otherwise you might be able to apply similar logic to force:recordEdit

AURA

```
<lightning:recordForm aura:id="createCaseForm"
        recordTypeId= "{!v.recordTypeId}" 
        onsubmit="{!c.handleCaseSubmit}"
        objectApiName="Case"
        fields="{!v.caseFields}"
        mode="edit"
        columns="2"
        variant="brand"
        >
    </lightning:recordForm>
```

JS

```
doSaveAction : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    event.preventDefault(); // stop form submission
    var eventFields = event.getParam("fields"); // gets all the fields for the object
    eventFields["AccountId"] = cmp.get("v.accountId");
    eventFields["ContactId"] = cmp.get("v.contactId");
    eventFields["Status"] = "In Process";
    cmp.find('createCaseForm').submit(eventFields);
},
```

Comment: Will it create the layout automatically as per the record type?

Comment: Yes, it will grab the page layout based on record type.  I also discovered a way to hide specific fields like recordId, let me know if you run into that issue and I'll send it your way

Comment: any luck getting it to work?

Comment: pls mark this answer as the correct answer if this worked